# Upgrading sources.list.d

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, reprepro

We have a reprepro-server which hosts some packages we have developed for our Ubuntu-systems. It contains packages for precies and trusty. Our systems have the reprepro-server configured in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

When we upgrade a system from precise to trusty the sources.list.d-entry gets disabled. How can we configure our systems or reprepro-server contiunue using our sources and upgrade the packages from one version to the next?